# How do I loop through functions for each product in my cart

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add more rows to my table, using the data from my cart page.How do I loop through functions for each product in my cart.

I have tried below code it works for single row but when I am trying to add more rows the table header keeps adding where as I want the table header only once and insert rows to the table. How do I do this can anyone help me pls?

```js
function summary() {  

    myObj = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
 myObj =JSON.parse(myObj);
 console.log(myObj);
   
 let summaryContainer = document.querySelector(".summary");
  console.log(summaryContainer); 
 
 
 if(myObj && summaryContainer) {  
  summaryContainer.innerHTML ='';
   Object.values(myObj).map(item => {
  summaryContainer.innerHTML += `
   <div class="product">
  <table class="product-table" border="2"  width="130%">
   <thead class="product-table__header">
    <tr>
    <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Product image</span></th>
    <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Description</span></th>
    <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Quantity</span></th>
    <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Price</span></th> 
   </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  <td class="product_image">
  <img src="./images/${item.tag}.jpg">
  </td>
  <td id="Description"> 
            <span>${item.name}</span>
  </td> 
  <td id="price"> 
   <div class="price">$${item.price}</div>
  </td>
  <td id="quantity">
   <div class="quantity">    
   <span>${item.incart}</span>    
   </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>  
   `;
  });
 }
  
}
 
summary();
```

```html
<div class="col-50"> 
    <div id ="orderSummary"> 
        <h2>Order summary</h2>     
        <div class ="summary-container" style ="padding-bottom: 0px;"> 
         <div class ="summary" style ="width:400px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the json format of `productsInCart `, please share that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the table to your html code and then add the rows dynamically 
try this

```
<div class="col-50"> 
  <div id ="orderSummary"> 
    <h2>Order summary</h2> 


    <div class ="summary-container" style ="padding-bottom: 0px;"> 
   <div class ="summary" style ="width:400px">
   <div class="product">
   <table class="product-table" id='mytable' border="2"  width="130%">
    <thead class="product-table__header">
     <tr>
     <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Product image</span></th>
     <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Description</span></th>
     <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Quantity</span></th>
     <th scope="col"><span class="visually-hidden">Price</span></th> 
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
   </table> 

   </div>
 </div>

   </div>
 </div>

<!-----Code------>
 <script>
   function summary() {  

myObj = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
 myObj = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
myObj =JSON.parse(myObj);

let summaryContainer = document.getElementById('mytable').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

if(myObj && summaryContainer) {     
 Object.values(myObj).map(item => {

summaryContainer.innerHTML += `

<tr>
<td class="product_image">
<img src="./images/${item.tag}.jpg">
</td>
<td id="Description"> 
        <span>${item.name}</span>
</td> 
<td id="price"> 
  <div class="price">$${item.price}</div>
</td>
<td id="quantity">
  <div class="quantity">             
  <span>${item.incart}</span>            
  </div>
</td>
</tr>

  `
});
}

}

summary();

 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks It is working, but it is printing only the last product in the list what do I do if I want to loop through each product In the cart

Comment: I have fixed that and updated the code, add `+` it to this `summaryContainer.innerHTML +=`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you mixed up the creation of the table with the appending of rows. Let's create a `generateRow` function:

```
function generateRow(item) {
    return `
    <td class="product_image">
    <img src="./images/${item.tag}.jpg">
    </td>
    <td id="Description"> 
        <span>${item.name}</span>
    </td> 
    <td id="price"> 
        <div class="price">$${item.price}</div>
    </td>
    <td id="quantity">
        <div class="quantity">           
        <span>${item.incart}</span>          
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    `;
}
```

and now this will be agnostic to the use-case. You can generate a row when you create the table, you can generate rows in a loop, you can generate rows when you append, whatever you need. Let's refactor your function:

```
function summary() {     

    myObj = localStorage.getItem("productsInCart");
    myObj =JSON.parse(myObj);
    console.log(myObj);

    let summaryContainer = document.querySelector(".summary");
     console.log(summaryContainer); 


    if(myObj && summaryContainer) {     
        summaryContainer.innerHTML ='';
        Object.values(myObj).map(item => {
        summaryContainer.innerHTML += generateRow(item);
        });
    }

}
```

And you can create an `addRow` `function`:

```
function addRow(table, item) {
    table.innerHTML += generateRow(item);
}
```